# Is SQL/JSON supported by SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-12

I'm interested, are these Postgresql-12 functions supported by sqlalchemy 1.3?

- `jsonb_path_exists(jsonb, jsonpath[, jsonb, bool])`
- `jsonb_path_match(jsonb, jsonpath[, jsonb, bool])`
- `jsonb_path_query(jsonb, jsonpath[, jsonb, bool])`
- `jsonb_path_query_array(jsonb, jsonpath[, jsonb, bool])`
- `jsonb_path_query_first(jsonb, jsonpath[, jsonb, bool])`

Answer (score 4):

Yes – you can use `func` to produce just about any function expression: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html. For example:

```
import json

from sqlalchemy import func

# Usually this'd be a column in your model
target = '{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'
path = '$.a[*] ? (@ >= $min && @ <= $max)'
# Use json.dumps to produce a valid json(b) literal from Python
vars_ = json.dumps({"min": 2, "max": 4})

engine.execute(select([func.jsonb_path_query(target, path, vars_)]))
```

Comment: Okey, thank you! Can we use `func` in the `query(...)` function?

Comment: Yes, see for example https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#counting. It produces an SQL function expression, so you can use it in a query where you can use function expressions.